# `__init__` decorator that handles args if empty

Tags: python, decorator

Let's say I have a class as such:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

My goal is to create a `decorator` that handles populating the `init` args if they do not exist, i.e.:

```
class Test:
    @autoinit
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

where `@autoinit` is defined as such:

```
class autoinit:
    def __init__(self, data = {"a": "test_a", "b": "test_b"}):
        self.data = data
    def __call__(self, func):
        decorator = self
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(decorator.data)
            func(self, **decorator.data)
            print(decorator.data)
        return wrapper
```

Thus, it will automatically assign the `Test` attributes to `test_a, test_b` respectively.

The ideal usage would be as such:

```
test = Test(a="test_z", b="test_x")
test.a == "test_z"
test.b == "test_x"

# however,

test = Test()
test.a == "test_a"
test.b == "test_b"

# but also,

test = Test(a="test_z")
test.a == "test_z"
test.b == "test_b"
```

I will always have matching arguments in the `Test` class to the keys in the `data` dictionary.

Is this possible?  What is the cleanest implementation?

---

Update:

The intended use is across many independent classes. For example, say I have a global config as such:

```
config = {
    "resourceA": {"a": "test_a", "b": "test_b"},
    "resourceB": {"name": "foo", "value": "bar"}
}
```

The goal would be for the decorator `@autoinit(resource="resourceA")` to use `**config[resource]` to populate all `__init__` values for given class.

Comment: Why do you want a decorator for this, rather than just giving `a` and `b` default values?

Comment: Because this will be used across many classes and a configuration dict that has a `test` key.. the ideal usage will be `@autoinit(resource="test")` and will contain `init` as `**config[resource]`.

Comment: @chepner I could imagine a use case where there are a number of unrelated (in the OO sense) classes whose constructors all default to the same values, so this `@autoinit` becomes the source of truth for those values.

That said: I would probably implement that by reading some config rather than hard coding a dict in the initializer

Comment: Use parameterized fixtures or test functions with pytest, much easier: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html

Comment: @AdamSmith see comment above, that is the plan!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would write this:

```py
def autoinit(**kwargs):
    if not kwargs:
        kwargs = {"a": "test_a", "b": "test_b"}  # some default

    def wrapper(f):
        def wrapped(*args, **overrides):
            kwargs.update(overrides)  # update kwargs with overrides
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper
```

This allows an implementing class as described in your question:

```py
class Test:
    @autoinit()
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

t = Test()
assert t.a = 'test_a'
assert t.b = 'test_b'

t2 = Test(a='test_z')
assert t2.a = 'test_z'
assert t2.b = 'test_b'
```

---

With that all being said, consider instead using a mixin that teaches your class how to read from the configuration itself.

```py
from abc import ABC
class ConfigurationDefault(ABC):
    @classmethod
    def with_config_defaults(cls, config, **kwargs):
        new_kwargs = {**config, **kwargs}
        return cls(**new_kwargs)

class Test(ConfigurationDefault):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

config = {'resources': {'a': 'test_a', 'b': 'test_b'}}
t = Test.with_config_defaults(config['resources'])
t2 = Test.with_config_defaults(config['resources'], a='test_z')
```

Comment: Yea, you could use it as `@autoinit(**config['my_resource'])` to populate it with the default values you want from your config.

Comment: Awesome stuff, thank you so much!  Quick question, what is the need for `*_` in `autoinit`. Thank you for the `mixin` suggestion, I'll take a look!

Comment: @sgerbhctim Ah it's not needed, in fact. I threw it in to debug an error I'd introduced by neglecting to call `autoinit` in the decorator (so it was being passed the positional argument `self`), but never pulled it back out once I'd fixed that. I've edited the answer now.